# Can I change the program to use different programID?

Tags: anchor, solana-program, anchor-program

I need to deploy my current program with different programId. It's already deployed to the devnet. But I need to deploy it again to devnet using different programId. Is that possible?. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes!

there are 2 places you need to change the program keypair in order to deploy to a new address:

1. update the public key in your `declare_id!` macro in `lib.rs`
2. copy the new keypair file to `target/deploy/<program>-keypair.json`

> *optionally* if your `Anchor.toml` has an entry for `[programs.devnet]`, then update the public key for that block as well.

---

**Note**

managing the program at two different addresses simultaneously isn't really possible without constantly switching back and forth between the keypairs at the positions described above, so its best to either close or abandon the previous deployment address if migrating to a new one.

---

the next time you run `anchor deploy --provider.cluster d`, it will deploy the program to the new address represented by the keypair you've just migrated to.

if you want to permanently close and retrieve rent from the initial deployment, you can use the `solana program close` command to do so.

Comment: Do I need to delete old keypair file or can I keep the both?

Comment: you can keep both keypair files. if you plan on closing the previous deployment address, it won't serve much of a purpose to hang onto though

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer